# Debian netinst.iso - deb and udeb - why duplicate?

Tags: debian, package-management

I saw there are plenty of similar packages on debian-netinst.iso, in `udeb` and `deb` form. A `udeb` is a stripped down `deb`; why are there duplicates of full and "slim" versions?

Comment: Could you give some specific examples? The Debian installer requires some `.udeb` and `.deb` packages to function. If there are duplicates this could be a bug or a specific instance where having both is advantageous. Without knowing which packages are duplicated though this question will be hard to answer.

Answer (score 3):

They aren’t really duplicates, they have different purposes.

`udeb` packages are stripped-down packages containing only the minimal amount of files required for the installer. They are used to run the system during its installation. The idea behind these minimal packages is to reduce the run-time requirements of the installer.

The `deb` packages in the installer images are full-blown packages and are installed during installation.

Some packages appear in both forms in the installer because they are both used by the installer and part of the installation. For example, `btrfs-progs` appears as a `udeb` package because it can be used during installation (to create Btrfs volumes); it also appears as a `deb` package because it has to be installed on systems using Btrfs volumes.